# Hide variations that don't match

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-variations

So I'm currently working on a Woocommerce store that has lots of variations.

What I'm basically looking for is for the next variation to refresh based on what was chosen on the variation chosen before that.

For example, if you go on http://freelance.tstwebdesign.co.uk/platino/product/plain-platinum-court/,
I want to choose a selection from "Width" which should then refresh "Depth" showing only the depths available that match with that width.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

It's default function for not many variations. For many variations you can do it with function

```
    // Woo Commerce – Make Variations only appear when available
function custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold( $qty, $product ) {
return 500;
}

add_filter( ‘woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold’, ‘custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold’, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: this is not working for me - https://shupholstery.co.uk/shop/bespoke-apple-crate/personalised-footstool-storage-crate/ - I have no variations setup for "wool > grape velvet" but all the options are still visible... need to hide the options which are not related to the first option..,