# hide product attributes if their variations are not set (WooCommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How to hide product attributes if their variations are not set. Example: I have 3 different colors and 3 different sizes. But not for every color every size exists:

- Blue >>> M
- Yellow >>> M, L, XL
- Green >>> M, L, XL

I.e. for blue is only one size available (other variations arent set in variations). But if someone chooses blue, he can choose all sizes (should only see size M) and then get the WooCommerce wc-no-matching-variations info .

How to hide the other size-options if blue is selected?

I found this, but this isnt working:
[Hide variations that don't match Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186931/hide-variations-that-dont-match-woocommerce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are more than 30 variations in WooCommerce, AJAX will kick in and prevent the list from being filtered . This can be modified by adding this into functions.php

```
function custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold( $qty, $product ) {
    return 10;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 'custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I had a lot of variations, so i needed to increase return number as:

`return 100;`