# woocomerce wordpress product quality restriction

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

hi think i want to ask you have a car

> 3 accessories in blue color
>   to yellow color> 5 accessories

After the user chooses the main elements, I want to restrict the legislation and want to simplify the legislation a little differently. we can add normal quality products, but there are restrictions on the required options, how can we do?

blue> yes&no
green> no

how can i do the same

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add attributes.  I'd go with Color and Logo as 2 attributes.  Then you need to make a product and set it to variable product.  Then add both attributes on the product page. Then choose the combination of attributes you want togther on the "variations" tab of the product.

Update: Here are pictures of how you should set your products. You can view my test product I made here http://marketplace.tradingcardmint.com/product/test-size-color/

[image]

[image]

Comment: my English is weak, but I don't think you understand me.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920091/hide-product-attributes-if-their-variations-are-not-set-woocommerce&usg=ALkJrhhuLlfE1Dvi9Gr6knzYKylluTVKew

same problem but unsolved

thanks